# Soap query from wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to write a PHP script to retrieve some data from a server.
I have the wsdl file that contains these entries for the function that I need to call:

```
<xs:element name="getRecoveryPointByID" type="tns:getRecoveryPointByID"/>
<xs:complexType name="getRecoveryPointByID">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="diskSafe" type="tns:diskSafe"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="recoveryPointID" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My problem is I don't know how to call this function properly.
I tried different ways:

```
getRecoveryPointIDs(array('aecaaba8-c57b-4401-82a7-27775383b04b','1'));
```

But I really don't understand how it's works.
Can somebody helps me to understand how to build my query?

I'm a real beginner in PHP and soap.

Thanks in advance.

Benoît

Answer (score 0):

getRecoveryPointByID needs an object, not an array (that's what you get with 'complextypes')

Something like this, casting the arrray to an object (inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762136/accessing-a-soap-webservice-using-php-containing-a-complextype-in-the-wsdl)):

```
$soap_client->getRecoveryPointIDs(
   (object)array(
        'diskSafe' => 'aecaaba8-c57b-4401-82a7-27775383b04b',
        'recoveryPointID' => '1'
   ));
```

It'll probably require some tuning. There are other ways (using [soapvar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php), for example), but they're long and arduous. SOAP is such a pain...

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I think I can see where is my problem now.
The Soap call wait a diskSafe type and not an ID directly.

Comment: It was definitely a problem of type passed in the function.
It's now resolved :)